# RabbitMQ with SSL: None of the specified endpoints were reachable

Tags: c#, rabbitmq, centos, erlang, centos7

I followed this tutorial [link](https://www.vultr.com/docs/how-to-install-rabbitmq-on-centos-7/) and installed Rabbit MQ on Oracle Cloud server.  I am able to use Management Plugin in browser.  But when I try to push a message via dotnet I am getting this error.  Firewall is allowed for ports 5671,5672 and 15672 also in oracle ingress rules."

> "RabbitMQ.Client.Exceptions.BrokerUnreachableException: None of the
> specified endpoints were reachable\r\n ---> System.AggregateException:
> One or more errors occurred. (Connection failed)\r\n --->
> RabbitMQ.Client.Exceptions.ConnectFailureException: Connection
> failed\r\n ---> System.Net.Sockets.SocketException (11001): No such
> host is known.\r\n   at
> System.Net.NameResolutionPal.ProcessResult(SocketError errorCode,
> GetAddrInfoExContext* context)\r\n   at
> System.Net.NameResolutionPal.GetAddressInfoExCallback(Int32 error,
> Int32 bytes, NativeOverlapped* overlapped)\r\n--- End of stack trace
> from previous location ---\r\n   at
> RabbitMQ.Client.Impl.TcpClientAdapter.ConnectAsync(String host, Int32
> port)\r\n   at RabbitMQ.Client.Impl.TaskExtensions.TimeoutAfter(Task
> task, TimeSpan timeout)\r\n   at
> RabbitMQ.Client.Impl.SocketFrameHandler.ConnectOrFail(ITcpClient
> socket, AmqpTcpEndpoint endpoint, TimeSpan timeout)\r\n   --- End of
> inner exception stack trace ---\r\n   at
> RabbitMQ.Client.Impl.SocketFrameHandler.ConnectOrFail(ITcpClient
> socket, AmqpTcpEndpoint endpoint, TimeSpan timeout)\r\n   at
> RabbitMQ.Client.Impl.SocketFrameHandler.ConnectUsingAddressFamily(AmqpTcpEndpoint
> endpoint, Func`2 socketFactory, TimeSpan timeout, AddressFamily family)\r\n   at RabbitMQ.Client.Impl.SocketFrameHandler..ctor(AmqpTcpEndpoint endpoint, Func`2 socketFactory, TimeSpan connectionTimeout, TimeSpan
> readTimeout, TimeSpan writeTimeout)\r\n   at
> RabbitMQ.Client.ConnectionFactory.CreateFrameHandler(AmqpTcpEndpoint
> endpoint)\r\n   at
> RabbitMQ.Client.EndpointResolverExtensions.SelectOne[T](IEndpointResolver
> resolver, Func`2 selector)\r\n   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---\r\n   at RabbitMQ.Client.EndpointResolverExtensions.SelectOne[T](IEndpointResolver resolver, Func`2 selector)\r\n   at
> RabbitMQ.Client.Framing.Impl.AutorecoveringConnection.Init(IEndpointResolver
> endpoints)\r\n   at
> RabbitMQ.Client.ConnectionFactory.CreateConnection(IEndpointResolver
> endpointResolver, String clientProvidedName)\r\n   --- End of inner
> exception stack trace ---\r\n   at
> RabbitMQ.Client.ConnectionFactory.CreateConnection(IEndpointResolver
> endpointResolver, String clientProvidedName)\r\n   at "

when trying to run  rabbitmq-diagnostics listeners I am getting this error in logs

> ** Connection attempt from node '' rejected. Invalid challenge reply. **

Can anyone assist me on this issue?

Comment: How are egos accusing management plug-in?